# InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with 'B2.jpg'

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, tfrecord

I have a dataset of `tfrecords` that I'm trying to parse.
I am using this code to parse it:

```
image_size = [224,224]
def read_tfrecord(tf_record):
    features = {
        "filename": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string), # tf.string means bytestring
        "fun": tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),  
        "label": tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
    }
    tf_record = tf.parse_single_example(tf_record, features)

    filename = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf_record['filename'], channels=3)
    filename = tf.cast(filename, tf.float32) / 255.0  # convert image to floats in [0, 1] range
    filename = tf.reshape(filename, [*image_size, 3]) # explicit size will be needed for TPU

    label = tf.cast(tf_record['label'],tf.float32)

    return filename, label

def load_dataset(filenames):
    option_no_order = tf.data.Options()
    option_no_order.experimental_deterministic = False

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.with_options(option_no_order)
    #dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames, num_parallel_reads=16)
    dataset = dataset.interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset, cycle_length=32, num_parallel_calls=AUTO) # faster
    dataset = dataset.map(read_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTO)
    return dataset

train_data=load_dataset(train_filenames)
val_data=load_dataset(val_filenames)
test_data=load_dataset(test_filenames)
```

After running this code I get:
`train_data

<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((224, 224, 3), (?,)), types: (tf.float32, tf.float32)>`
 
I was trying to see the images in the dataset with:

```
def display_9_images_from_dataset(dataset):
    subplot=331
    plt.figure(figsize=(13,13))
    images, labels = dataset_to_numpy_util(dataset, 9)
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        title = CLASSES[np.argmax(labels[i], axis=-1)]
        subplot = display_one_flower(image, title, subplot)
        if i >= 8:
            break;

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
    plt.show()



def dataset_to_numpy_util(dataset, N):
    dataset = dataset.batch(N)

    if tf.executing_eagerly():
    # In eager mode, iterate in the Datset directly.
        for images, labels in dataset:
            numpy_images = images.numpy()
            numpy_labels = labels.numpy()
            break;

    else: # In non-eager mode, must get the TF note that 
        # yields the nextitem and run it in a tf.Session.
        get_next_item = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
        with tf.Session() as ses:
            numpy_images, numpy_labels = ses.run(get_next_item)

    return numpy_images, numpy_labels


display_9_images_from_dataset(train_data)
```

But I get the error:
`InvalidArgumentError:  Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with 'B2.jpg'
     [[{{node DecodeJpeg}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext_3]]`

I'm a bit confused, one because it says that the file is `jpg` format and it asks for `jpeg`, which from my understanding are the same.
And also because I'm not sure how to view the images or even know if I parsed it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Extensions ".jpg" and ".jpeg" are different in terms of the validation check done by the API which is consuming it.

tf.image.decode_jpeg takes images with ".jpeg" extensions.

Try renaming your .jpg images with .jpeg extensions and it should start working.

Comment: make sure that you only retrieve the .jpeg extensions like data_dir = './images/*/*.jpeg'